# d3.js dynamically append swarms with variable force bounds

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a grid system that I'm using to display basic data:

```
var columns = 5;
var spacing = 250;
var vSpacing = 180;

var bankG = graphGroup.selectAll('.bank')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'bank')
  .attr('id', (d, i) => 'bank' + i)
  .attr('transform', (d, k) => {
    var horSpace = (k % columns) * spacing;
    var vertSpace = ~~((k / columns)) * vSpacing;
    return "translate(" + horSpace + "," + vertSpace + ")";
  });
```

And my simplified data set looks like:

```
var data = [
  {'bank':'bank1','q1':100,'q2':120,'products':d3.range(20).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_fund'} })},
  {'bank':'bank2','q1':120,'q2':130,'products':d3.range(24).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_fund'} })},
  {'bank':'bank3','q1':140,'q2':150,'products':d3.range(80).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_fund'} })},
  {'bank':'bank4','q1':100,'q2':150,'products':d3.range(30).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_fund'} })},
  {'bank':'bank5','q1':90,'q2':120,'products':d3.range(10).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_fund'} })},
  {'bank':'bank6','q1':80,'q2':130,'products':d3.range(70).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_fund'} })}
];
```

I've already appended rects and circles to form the scaffolding of the visual. Next I want to append swarm clusters around the circle that we see that juts off to the right-hand side of each rect. The idea is that each mini circle will represent one product; hence I'm trying to point the swarm cluster to the data in `products`. Also important is that each swarm is to assume initial force logic using the static right-hand circles I appended above; call them placeholders.  Full snippet below:

```js
var margins = {
  top: 200,
  bottom: 300,
  left: 100,
  right: 100
};

var height = 450;
var width = 1100;

var totalWidth = width + margins.left + margins.right;
var totalHeight = height + margins.top + margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', totalWidth)
  .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', "translate(" + margins.left + "," + margins.top + ")");

var tsvData = d3.tsv('202105-xb.tsv');

//tsvData.then(function(rawData) {

//var data = rawData.map(function(d) {
//return {quota20:+d.quota20, quota21:+d.quota21, bank:d.bank, products:d3.range(+d.products).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_fund'} })}
//});


var data = [
  {'bank':'bank1','q1':100,'q2':120,'products':d3.range(20).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_fund'} })},
  {'bank':'bank2','q1':120,'q2':130,'products':d3.range(24).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_fund'} })},
  {'bank':'bank3','q1':140,'q2':150,'products':d3.range(80).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_fund'} })},
  {'bank':'bank4','q1':100,'q2':150,'products':d3.range(30).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_fund'} })},
  {'bank':'bank5','q1':90,'q2':120,'products':d3.range(10).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_fund'} })},
  {'bank':'bank6','q1':80,'q2':130,'products':d3.range(70).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_fund'} })}
];

var rScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([5, 25])
  .domain([0, 4000]);

var columns = 5;
var spacing = 250;
var vSpacing = 180;

var bankG = graphGroup.selectAll('.bank')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'bank')
  .attr('id', (d, i) => 'bank' + i)
  .attr('transform', (d, k) => {
var horSpace = (k % columns) * spacing;
var vertSpace = ~~((k / columns)) * vSpacing;
return "translate(" + horSpace + "," + vertSpace + ")";
  });

bankG.append('rect')
.attr('x',0)
.attr('y',0)
.attr('width', 50)
.attr('height', 50)
.style('fill', "#003366");

bankG.append('line')
.attr('x1',50)
.attr('x2',90)
.attr('y1',25)
.attr('y2',25)
.style('stroke',"#a6a6a6");

bankG.append('circle')
.attr('cx', 90)
.attr('cy', 25)
.attr('r', 12)
.style('fill',"#003366");

var forceNodes = data.each().products;

forceNodes.push({fx:0,fy:0,placeholder:true});

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(forceNodes)
.force("x", d3.forceX(function(d) {
return 20;
}).strength(0.2))
.force("y", d3.forceY(function(d) {
return 12.5;
}).strength(0.1))
.force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d) {

  return d.placeholder ? 12 : 4;
}).iterations(1))
.stop();

simulation.tick(75);

   d3.select(this).selectAll(null)
.data(forceNodes.filter(function(d) { return !d.placeholder }))
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("r", 3)
.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x;})
.attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y;})
.style('stroke',"none")
.style('fill', function(d) {return "#4f81b9"; })


//})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

It seems I didn't quite access the data correctly for the swarm bit:

> Uncaught TypeError: data.each is not a function

### Question

Essentially, I'm trying to figure out how I get my swarm clusters to read the `product` data and append tightly around my existing normal circles? (presumably requiring variable force logic like in my attempt)

Comment: `each` is a function of d3 selection. Since `data` is an array, you need `data.forEach`

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky Thanks for looking into it. That's probably a step in the right direction, but still threw a "undefined is not a function" error at me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm interpreting quite correctly, but if so, a solution could look like this:

You have nested data, the parent `g`, line, and rectangle have a different datum than the children in the force layout. So first we append the parent g and the line and rectangle contained by it. *I'm not appending what I understand to be the placeholder circle node as we can do that with the rest, otherwise, this is the same as before.*

Now we can apply a force layout to the nodes contained in the `products` property:

```
bankG.each(function(bank) {
  bank.products.push({fx:0,fy:0,placeholder:true})
  
  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(bank.products)
    .force("x", d3.forceX(function(d) {
       return 20;
     }).strength(0.2))
     .force("y", d3.forceY(function(d) {
       return 12.5;
     }).strength(0.1))
     .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d) {
       return d.placeholder ? 12 : 4;
     }).iterations(1))
     .stop();  
     simulation.tick(75);
})
```

With the products array updated with positional data based on the force layout, we can now do our nested enter. To do so we use the `products` property of the each parent `g` as the data array for the selection of children:

```
bankG.selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) { return d.products; })
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) {
       ...
```

Here's a quick example:

```js
var margins = {
  top: 200,
  bottom: 300,
  left: 100,
  right: 100
};

var height = 450;
var width = 1100;

var totalWidth = width + margins.left + margins.right;
var totalHeight = height + margins.top + margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', totalWidth)
  .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', "translate(" + margins.left + "," + margins.top + ")");

var tsvData = d3.tsv('202105-xb.tsv');

var data = [
  {'bank':'bank1','q1':100,'q2':120,'products':d3.range(20).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_fund'} })},
  {'bank':'bank2','q1':120,'q2':130,'products':d3.range(24).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_fund'} })},
  {'bank':'bank3','q1':140,'q2':150,'products':d3.range(80).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_fund'} })},
  {'bank':'bank4','q1':100,'q2':150,'products':d3.range(30).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_fund'} })},
  {'bank':'bank5','q1':90,'q2':120,'products':d3.range(10).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_fund'} })},
  {'bank':'bank6','q1':80,'q2':130,'products':d3.range(70).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_fund'} })}
];

var rScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([5, 25])
  .domain([0, 4000]);

var columns = 5;
var spacing = 250;
var vSpacing = 180;

var bankG = graphGroup.selectAll('.bank')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'bank')
  .attr('id', (d, i) => 'bank' + i)
  .attr('transform', (d, k) => {
var horSpace = (k % columns) * spacing;
var vertSpace = ~~((k / columns)) * vSpacing;
return "translate(" + horSpace + "," + vertSpace + ")";
  });

bankG.append('rect')
.attr('x',0)
.attr('y',0)
.attr('width', 50)
.attr('height', 50)
.style('fill', "#003366");

bankG.append('line')
.attr('x1',50)
.attr('x2',90)
.attr('y1',25)
.attr('y2',25)
.style('stroke',"#a6a6a6");

// For each bankG:
bankG.each(function(bank) {
  bank.products.push({fx:0,fy:0,placeholder:true})
  
  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(bank.products)
    .force("x", d3.forceX(function(d) {
       return 20;
     }).strength(0.2))
     .force("y", d3.forceY(function(d) {
       return 12.5;
     }).strength(0.1))
     .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d) {
       return d.placeholder ? 12 : 4;
     }).iterations(1))
     .stop();  
     simulation.tick(75);
})

bankG.selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) { return d.products; })
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.placeholder ? 12 : 3;
  })
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x + 90})
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y + 25})
  .style('stroke',"none")
  .style('fill', function(d) {
    return d.placeholder ? "#003366" : "#4f81b9"; 
   })

//})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice approach! Is there a way to make the swarms concentric with the big circles? (would hug top and bottom more and spread out left and right equally if n is big.

Comment: Seems like the centers can be aligned with a quick tweak on the swarm x&ys. Problem solved, this is so cool, thanks again